# How to pass a char array to fopen_s

Tags: c, fopen

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int i;
    char name[20];
    FILE * src;
    FILE * des;
    fgets(name,20,stdin); 
    fopen_s(&src,"배경사진.jpg", "rb");
    fopen_s(&des,name,"wb");
    char buf[20];
    int readcnt;

    if (src == NULL || des == NULL) {
        puts("파일 오픈 실패!");
        return -1;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        readcnt = fread((void*)buf, 1, sizeof(buf), src);

        if (readcnt < sizeof(buf))
        {
            if (feof(src) != 0)
            {
                fwrite((void*)buf, 1, readcnt, des);


                puts("파일복사 완료");
            }
            else
                puts("파일복사 실패");

            break;
        }
```

i wanna get (new file's name to be copied) in cmd.
generally `fopen_s(&des,"~.jpg", "wb");` is used.
but i used char array instead of `"~.jpg"`.

how do i do to make program user can put..

Comment: Aside: are you sure you have the sense of `feof` the right way round? It returns a nonzero value if a read operation has attempted to read past the end of the file, yet you treat that as a success. The usual way to use `fread` in a loop is to control the loop with the number of items read. Such as with `while ((readcnt = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), src)) != 0) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem.

```
fgets(name,20,stdin); 

fopen_s(&des,name,"wb");
```

Your `fopen_s` will fail as `fgets` adds line feed character to the `name`.

Hence you need to trim the line feed char from the `name`.

Example:

```
size_t len = strlen(name);
if (len > 0 && name[len - 1] == '\n')
    name[len - 1] = '\0';

fopen_s(&des,name,"wb");
```

Comment: thank you for answering . that's amazing to be answered by another country people.!